# custom SWT component blinks when I interact with it

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I'm building a small suite of widgets ([here](https://github.com/germantech/ios-widgets)) for SWT.
I've done a Slider, but every time I change thevalue with the mouse wheel, it kinda blinks.

The source is available [here](https://github.com/germantech/ios-widgets/blob/master/br.com.germantech.iosWidgets.plugin/src/br/com/germantech/ioswidgets/slider/IOSSlider.java).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` to the component when instantiating they